How to keep directory structure and only .htaccess files in Git while ignoring everything else?
I want to keep the directory structure under out/ and only track .htaccess files in my Git repository. All other files and subdirectories should be ignored.
Here is my directory structure:
out/
├── .htaccess
├── target1/
│   └── .htaccess
├── target2/
│   └── .htaccess
├── target3/
│   └── .htaccess
└── other-files-and-folders/

My current .gitignore file looks like this:
out/*
!out/.htaccess
!out/target1/.htaccess
!out/target2/.htaccess
!out/target3/.htaccess

Problem:
This configuration does not track the .htaccess files in subdirectories (out/target1/.htaccess, etc.). When I run git status, they do not appear. Using git check-ignore, it shows that the .htaccess files are still being ignored.
Goal:

Track .htaccess files in all subdirectories.
Preserve the directory structure (empty folders are not necessary).
Ignore all other files under out/.

How should I modify my .gitignore file to achieve this?

The docs say: "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded." You have, in the first line, excluded all the directories in out. So you cannot then include anything in any of those directories.

Note that you can simply force-add the ignored files (git add -f out/.htaccess, etc), and then they will be tracked. Patterns in .gitignore are only relevant for files that aren't already tracked in the repository.

I would suggest to combibe find and git add -f:
find out/ -name .htaccess | xargs -r git add -f


You can also unleash the gitignore pattern from hell:
# in out/. gitignore
*           # 1. ignore everything ...
!*/         # 2. except directories
!.htaccess  # 3. and anything named .htaccess

The presence of the second pattern will make git scan each individual directory rather than completely skip it.
I'm jokingly saying "from hell", because this will still scan the complete content of your out/ directory even for a simple git status.
If you choose this option, test if the performances of git status or git add out/ are acceptable.
